# How can I return a count of a specific criteria in a range of duplicated items?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two sheets (tabs) in an excel document, Sheet 1 and 2.  As can be seen below Sheet 1 has 3 columns [1 row], and Sheet 2 has 2 columns [5 rows].

I am looking for a formula that will return the values that is in Sheet 1, Column C (i.e. 3). I am able to do a countif formula to find the count of the item in Sheet 1, Column A; but what formula would work to get the value of dates that are equal to or greater than 2013 in Sheet 2, Column B.

```
Sheet 1
Column A:Item   Column B:Count   Column C:=>2013
1. P02853          5                3 

Sheet 2
Column A     Column B
1. P02853    2014
2. P02853    2011 
3. P02853    2015
4. P02853    2013 
5. P02853    2010
```

How can I return a count of a specific criteria in a range of duplicated items?

Answer (score 2):

For several conditions on a count, you can use `COUNTIFS` instead of `COUNTIF`. The syntax is much the same, the only thing you lacked to obtain your objective was knowing that you can add comparison operators to your conditions. I think that in the case you are asking about, the formula would look something like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A1:A5;Sheet1!A1;Sheet2!B1:B5;">="&2013)
```

I assume that the first set of conditions look similar to what you already have in `B1` of sheet 1, and the second set of conditions isn't much more complicated, I've simple added on a comparison operator (greater than or equal to) before the value I want to to compare B1:B5 of sheet 2 to.